# showing error while creating a button widget

Tags: flutter, dart

Here `CuButton` shows an error. I also created the same widget but it does not show errors elsewhere, however, in this case, it shows an error

```
Widget CuBUtton({
    String name = "button",
    Color color = Colors.blueGrey,
    double H = 10,
    double W = 10,
    required Function function,
    required TextStyle Labelstyl}) {
    try {
      return
        InkWell(onTap: () {
          function();
        },
          child: Container(color: color,
            height: H, width: W,
            child: Center(child:
            Text(name,style: Labelstyl,)),),
        );
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error on Button $e");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the required `keyword` from the `function`:

```
Widget CuButton({
    String name = "button",
    Color color = Colors.blueGrey,
    double H = 10,
    double W = 10,
    Function function,
    TextStyle Labelstyl}) {
  try {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        function();
      },
      child: Container(
        color: color,
        height: H,
        width: W,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(name, style: Labelstyl),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } catch (e) {
    print("Error on Button $e");
  }
}
```